# Java indexing arrays with keywords

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I am currently making a small game and I was wondering how to replace numbered indexes with keywords, for example:

Instead of:

```
private boolean keyStroke = new boolean[4];

if(pressing up key) {
    keyStroke[0] = true;
}
```

I would like:

```
private boolean keyStroke = new boolean[4];

if(pressing up key) {
    keyStroke[up] = true;
}
```

I found that this is possible by making variables such as int up = 0; but is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Map` instead of an array:

```
Map<String, Boolean> keyStrokeMap = new HashMap<>();

if (pressing up key) {
    keyStrokeMap.put("up", true);
}
```

Then when you check for a given direction you can use `Map.get()`:

```
booelan pressedUp = keyStrokeMap.get("up");
```

Comment: I see he just need constant like enum